# Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined" when trying to format a date field

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to format a date field in my ionic project. THis date field is being read in from Firebase and I try to format it in the html page but I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined

The strange thing is that it displays as I would expect on screen but I'm not sure why the console error is displayed

Attaching the .html, related .ts and .service.ts

Here is the html code: (note that removing the format section I do not get the error)

```
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>
           DOB: <font>{{currentPlayerDetails?.dateOfBirth.seconds * 1000 | 
                       date:'d/MMM/yyyy' }}</font>
       </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

A snippet of the related .ts file

```
 export class PlayerDetailsPage implements OnInit {

   public currentPlayerDetails: any = {};

      constructor(private playersService: PlayersService,private 
 helperService: HelperService, 
                private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      const playerId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
       this.playersService.getPlayerDetails(playerId).get()
       .then(playerDetailsSnapshot=> {
          this.currentPlayerDetails = playerDetailsSnapshot.data();
          this.currentPlayerDetails.id = playerDetailsSnapshot.id;

       });
  }
 }
```

And finally some of the .service.ts file

```
export class PlayersService {

 public playersRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;

   constructor() { 
     this.playersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('/players');   
  }


     getPlayerDetails(playerDetailsId: string): 
    firebase.firestore.DocumentReference {
               return this.playersRef.doc(playerDetailsId);        
         }
 }
```

Output of the console.log of this.currentPlayerDetails

```
{
  "country": "UK",
  "county": "Warwickshire",
  "dateOfBirth": {
    "seconds": 527986800,
    "nanoseconds": 0
  },
  "firstName": "Kevin",
  "photoLocation": "",
  "position": "Midfield",
  "surname": "Browne",
  "team": "Mens",
  "town": "Birmingham",
  "id": "HVbUmm1KwKjy9fwtsCdP"
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166977/rendering-a-firestore-timestamp-in-react

Answer (score 0):

As the error is clearly saying, the `dateOfBirth` is undefined and that's why it can't find property `seconds` of undefined. I would suggest try console priting of `currentPlayerDetails` and see what data you are getting from firebase.

Also I see its returning a promise, please use async/await to make sure that is available when ngOnInit completes. This [blog](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8) is good reference to understand how promise works.

**UPDATE: EXPLAINATION**

You are binding `listener/subscriber` inside `ngOnInit` to `firebase` call which returns a `promise`, and inside the `subscriber` you are updating the value of class property `currentPlayerDetails` which you have bound to the angular view. So when your page loads/inits angular completes its `NgOnInit` lifecycle hooks to bound subscriber to `firebase promise` but its not haulting the page load event until the `promise` resolves (i.e. the data is fetch), but it does eventually resolves and updates the `currentPlayerDetails` class property.

*This all happens within fraction of seconds, you can't barely notice the UI changes in the view. And that's why you see the error in console(this is when promise is not yet resolved but page load event is occuring) but the UI displays the data (at this point everything is loaded & promise is resolved as well), since the process is `asynchronous`.*

The right way to consume a promise synchronously through use of `async/await`, this will get rid of your console error:

```
export class PlayerDetailsPage implements OnInit {

    public currentPlayerDetails: any = {};

    constructor(private playersService: PlayersService,
        private helperService: HelperService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchPlayerDetails(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    }

    private async fetchPlayerDetails(playerId: string) {
        const playerDetailsSnapshot = await this.playersService.getPlayerDetails(playerId).get();
        this.currentPlayerDetails = playerDetailsSnapshot.data();
        this.currentPlayerDetails.id = playerDetailsSnapshot.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I console print currentPlayerDetails if prints the details I would expect so I don't think thats the issue.

When I remove ".seconds * 1000" from 
<ion-label>
           DOB: <font>{{currentPlayerDetails?.dateOfBirth.seconds * 1000 | 
                       date:'d/MMM/yyyy' }}</font>
       </ion-label>
I don't see any errors (the negative of this is my date is printing as an unreadable timestamp

@AmithKumar

Comment: Then please update your answer with value of `currentPlayerDetails` object, to give us more insight.

Comment: added output on the original question above. I really appreciate you taking a look - thanks for your help.

Comment: Its not very clear print format of your object, use JSON.stringify(object) to print. From your provided info, it almost prints like the seconds property exists directly inside the currentPlayerDetails.

Comment: {"country":"UK","county":"Warwickshire","dateOfBirth":{"seconds":527986800,"nanoseconds":0},"firstName":"Kevin","photoLocation":"","position":"Midfield","surname":"Browne","team":"Mens","town":"Birmingham","id":"HVbUmm1KwKjy9fwtsCdP"}

Comment: updated my answer to give more insight. It might have syntactical error as I don't have full code context, but this should give you headstart. However, I definitely recommend reading through that blog I referred earlier to understand & rightly implement promise, I understand it gets confusing and will take time to get used to it, even pros makes silly mistakes with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it makes sense and you described it very clearly. I have refactored the code to now include async and await - the syntax is ok and the functionality has not changes however I still receive the console error.

The console error repeats over and over again. i.e. its the same error but it appears a random number of times when I got on to that particular page. e.g. I got it 44 times now and 56 earlier.

Would this suggest that the error is not related to synchronicity?

Comment: At this point, I can only say put more console.log around the codebase i.e. in ngOnInit & getPlayerDetails method, and also add more ng lifecycle [hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) in your view class with console log, and see what is causing your page/data to re-load recursively.

Comment: Probably not the best solution but it gets rid of my console error. I've added an ngIf to the html tag - <font *ngIf="currentPlayerDetails?.dateOfBirth">

Answer (score 0):

You should use Async/Await functions when dealing with firebase calls since almost everything is asynchronous, this is why it probably doesn´t have any value to format at that moment.

Try reading [this](https://javebratt.com/async-await/) post and maybe it will help you.

Comment: When I console print currentPlayerDetails if prints the details I would expect so I don't think thats the issue.

When I remove ".seconds * 1000" from 
<ion-label>
           DOB: <font>{{currentPlayerDetails?.dateOfBirth.seconds * 1000 | 
                       date:'d/MMM/yyyy' }}</font>
       </ion-label>
I don't see any errors (the negative of this is my date is printing as an unreadable timestamp

@Mario